# Nvim setup instructions for the layman?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to install vim and [nvim](https://github.com/cwoac/nvim) as a replacement for Notational Velocity. I recently migrated to Ubuntu (14.04) and I'm very new to how everything works. The instructions for installing nvim are kind of elliptic and not entirely clear to me as a beginner. I manage to get it running if I enter vim and then type :Nvim inside the directory where I store my .txt notes. However, the notes aren't visible in nvim and here's where I run into trouble. As a beginner I simply do not understand the instructions regarding `PATH` and `:python` that are given on the installation page. I've tried (successfully, I think) to install xapian as well (after having installed vim) but nothing changed. That is, I cannot specify a `PATH` for my `nvim` and I cannot get the `nvim` script to work as a command anywhere in the terminal.

More consequentially, when I type

```
:python nvimdb.rebuild_database()
```

inside vim, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
NameError: name 'nvimdb' is not defined
```

What I would like to ask for are step by step instructions for making nvim work with an existing library of .txt notes targeted at the vim and linux novice.

The program looks great and appears to be exactly what I need for my note taking needs, and I would really appreciate your help! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is probably because you haven't installed the xapian library as that is a required mentioned by nvim. You need to install the package `xapian-core` I believe, you can do that in ubuntu with something like this : `sudo apt-get install xapian-core`

Comment: I think I have it installed (not through that method: it cannot find `xapian-core`), but I installed it after I had installed `vim`. Does that matter? How do I find it if it's installed and working properly?

Comment: Is your vim compiled with +python ? You can check by `vim --version | grep python` or within vim `:echo has('python')`.

Comment: Regarding checking if it's installed correctly, just open a python repl (ipython?) and type `import xapian`, if that doesn't fail you should consider opening a ticket on nvim's issue tracker, the author should be able to help you out better.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that it is compiled with +python and I could `import xapian`. It didn't make any difference as far as my travails with `nvim` are concerned however. I have written a post on their github, perhaps I'll hear back from them there. In the meantime, thank you.